# How does $N_H\theta^{N_H−1} (1−\theta)^{N_T}−\theta^{N_H} N_T (1−\theta)^{N_T−1} = 0$ become $N_H(1−\theta)−\theta N_T = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to solve for $\theta$, in the solutions, it gave this but I'm just wondering how did $(1)$ get to $(2)$?

$$\begin{align}
N_H\theta^{N_H−1} (1−\theta)^{N_T}−\theta^{N_H} N_T (1−\theta)^{N_T−1} &= 0 \tag1 \\[4pt]
N_H(1−\theta)−\theta N_T &= 0 \tag2\\[4pt]
N_H &= N_H\theta + N_T\theta \tag3 \\[4pt]
\theta &= \frac{N_H}{N_H + N_T} \tag4
\end{align}$$

Comment: Divide the equation by $\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid case distinctions I assume that $\theta\in(0,1)$. Other cases are analogous or easier.
Consider the equation
$$0=N_H\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T}-\theta^{N_H}N_T(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}.$$
Divide both sides by $\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}$, then we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{0}{\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}}&=\frac{N_H\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T}-\theta^{N_H}N_T(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}}{\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}}\\
0&=\frac{N_H\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T}}{{\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}}}-\frac{\theta^{N_H}N_T(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}}{\theta^{N_H-1}(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}}\\
0&=N_H(1-\theta)-\theta N_T.
\end{align*}

Comment: But how did you go from the second line to the third line? I tried cancelling the common factors and then merging them together and moving the denominator over to the LHS where the 0 is; to eliminate the denominator but the answer doesn't seem to get to the last line...

Comment: For the first quotient, notice the $\theta^{N_H-1}$ in the numerator and also in the denominator. These two cancel out completely. Then we have $(1-\theta)^{N_T}=(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}(1-\theta)$ in the numerator, and $(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}$ in the denominator, so $(1-\theta)^{N_T-1}$ cancels out and we're left with $(1-\theta)$ in the numerator. Taking the $N_H$ in the numerator into account, we're left with $N_H(1-\theta)$. We only used [simple arithmetic for fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction#Arithmetic_with_fractions), nothing else. The second quotient can be treated analogously.